# default radio buttons are getting selected PHP

Tags: php

I am new to php and MYSQL. For Morrocan oil, the radio buttons are getting checked when I click on Yes or No. But, the printStatement when I click is Yes/No. The default No is getting checked no matter what. Can you please help me resolve this issue. Thanks!

```
echo '<tr>
                <td>' . _('Signed Moroccan Oil?') . '</td>';
                if(strtoupper($_POST['signedMor']) == 'YES'){
                    echo '<td>  <input type="radio" name="signedMor" id="signedMor" value="Yes" checked="checked">Yes
                                <input type="radio" name="signedMor" id="signedMor" value="No">No</td>';
                } else {
                    echo '<td>  <input type="radio" name="signedMor" id="signedMor" value="Yes">Yes
                                <input type="radio" name="signedMor" id="signedMor" value="No" checked="checked">No</td>';
                }
        echo '</tr>';



        echo '<tr>
                <td>' . _('Print Statement?') . '</td>';
                if(strtoupper($_POST['printStatement']) == 'Y'){
                    echo '<td>  <input type="radio" name="printStatement" id="printStatement" value="Y" checked="checked">Yes
                                <input type="radio" name="printStatement" id="printStatement" value="N">No</td>';
                } else {
                    echo '<td>  <input type="radio" name="printStatement" id="printStatement" value="Y">Yes
                                <input type="radio" name="printStatement" id="printStatement" value="N" checked="checked">No</td>';
                }
        echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: Is getting checked as "NO", all the time after the form is submitted?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's checked as "No".

Comment: It looks like $_POST['printStatement']  is not holding the right value

Comment: Thank you! I checked. But the database is getting updated properly. When I click on yes,' No' remains checked.

Comment: That is impossible. Sorry, but the only way your code can result in "NO" always being checked is, that `$_POST['printStatement']` does not hold the correct value. If it does, it works. Your issue might be completely elsewhere. DOes your browser save form inputs, maybe?

Comment: Thanks it's resolved now.